# White dots appearing on the drift wood surface

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, aquatic-plants

In my newly set aquarium, white dots are appearing over the drift wood surface. I don't know what it is and don't know how to avoid it. Its a newly planted aquarium with no fish. I haven't introduced fishes into it yet. Please someone tell me how to stop that white dots I don't want to spoil my setup.

Comment: Have you got Nerite snails in your tank? I get these and they look like a sesame seed but are snail eggs. Depending on where your plants came from you may have got snails with the plants.

Comment: No, I ain't got any snails and also fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So most driftwoods are boiled down or treated at some point to be safe for all types of aquariums and terrariums. When dried out and then placed back into water, marine or fresh a fungus can grow, sounds hard to believe that sterilization will lead to fungal growth but it's true. It'll start as white tiny docs, then patches, then spread to a fuzzy like film. Some growth in tanks are safe, and this is one of them. If you take it out, scrub it off or boil and put back in it'll come back, you are stuck with it BUT there is a solution. Shrimp will eat it, and and some catfish will too!

Forever ago I found an article about this online,but I can't remember how I stumbled upon it. If I find it, I'll edit to add the link!

Comment: You're exactly right it has a fuzzy like film over it. Can Flourish Excel solve this issue? Because I've read this product disappears the algae and fungus from tank.

Comment: Not that I know of... Flourish excel is a bio organic source of carbon for boosting aquatic plant growth and CO2 does help with fungus but CO2(carbon dioxide) isn't the origin of the carbon in Flourish Excel. Try it! It will do NO HARM to try! This fungus will also disappear as your tank becomes more established, but you're in for a wait time without the fish I spoke of. If you like Seachem products try their Stability, healthy bacteria booster for establishing biofilter, it may lessen wait time.

Comment: Is this a plant only tank? Or do you plan on putting fish in later?

Comment: I'm planning to put neon tetra or cardinal tetra. Its a 2 week tank, someone from internet suggested me to add the fishes when the plants gets established completely. I got Japanese hair grass, vivipara grass and ludwigia sp mini red. Ludwigias are growing new leaves, viviparas are touching the sky and my Japanese hair grass doesn't looks good. They are growing but not like viviparas. I'm using contro soil as the substrate.

Comment: Okay, with that said, since you're using contro soil, scratch the catfish idea and stick with some shrimp, you can use them to cycle your tank too and wait a few days before adding the neons or Cardinals you mentioned. Do regular water testing, some contro soil is made from volcanic soil, is PACKED FULL of nutrients, but also slowly releases ammonia from organic matter. Sounds beautiful by the way! How exciting! Don't ya just hate having to wait for fish?! Good luck